# helm dependency follow-up connection breaks

Tags: kubernetes-helm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgrgO.png)

My network is able to access the address 20.205.243.166:443, but the connection is dropped when pulling the index.yml

What causes it anymore, I am puzzled as to how this problem should be solved